# Maketrans in Python 2.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got this nice little method to remove control characters from a string. Unfortunatelly, it does not work in Python 2.6 (only in Python 3.1). It states:

> ```
> mpa = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(control_chars))
> ```
>
> AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'

```
def removeControlCharacters(line):
   control_chars = (chr(i) for i in range(32))
   mpa = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(control_chars))
   return line.translate(mpa)
```

How can it be rewritten?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this instance, there is no need for `maketrans` for either byte strings or Unicode strings:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> delete_chars=''.join(chr(i) for i in xrange(32))
>>> '\x00abc\x01def\x1fg'.translate(None,delete_chars)
'abcdefg'
```

or:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> delete_chars = dict.fromkeys(range(32))
>>> u'\x00abc\x01def\x1fg'.translate(delete_chars)
u'abcdefg'
```

or even in Python 3:

```
Python 3.1.3 (r313:86834, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:53) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> delete_chars = dict.fromkeys(range(32))
>>> '\x00abc\x01def\x1fg'.translate(delete_chars)
'abcdefg'
```

See `help(str.translate)` and `help(unicode.translate)` (in Python2) for details.

Comment: For those who may be trying something like the second example... if you get the error `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`, it could mean the string you're trying to translate is not unicode. (No doubt this is obvious to Mark, but not to noobs like me.)

Answer (score 17):

In Python 2.6, `maketrans` is in [the string module](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans). Same with Python 2.7.

So instead of `str.maketrans`, you'd first `import string` and then use `string.maketrans`.